# html: any way to "wrap" a web page with an auto-reload function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a status page that I would like to periodically reload.  Instead of coding a refresh action into the page itself, I would like to have a wrapper page handle the periodic reloading.  Any such thing available off the shelf?

Something I could use like this would be perfect:

```
http://foo/automatic-page-reloader?interval=60&page=http://foo/mypage.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to delve into JavaScript or anything like that, you could simply use an IFRAME where the framed page has a META refresh tag.  e.g.:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" />
```

Comment: This would work well with the example URL, since you can set both your refresh interval and iframe `src` attribute by pulling the data out of the GET request.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your wrapper page contain some javascript and a frame.

The javascript would execute a `reload()` call on the frame every once in a while using a [`setTimeOut()`](http://www.netlobo.com/javascript_location_reload.html) call.

A sample solution to this problem can be seen [here](http://www.ozzu.com/website-design-forum/javascript-refresh-problem-t44537.html#p223168).